# How do I port characters expressed as decimals?

Tags: delphi, unicode

How do I port characters expressed as decimals (#0, #1, #9, #10, #13, #32, #128, #255) in Delphi 7 to Delphi Unicode? Some documents (such as 'Delphi in a Unicode world' from Embarcadero) only says that they should be replaced with the actual character. For example instead of #128 I should use '€'. But what would you do with #0??? Or #9? Or #13?

---

Update:

It looks like this is a tricky question. Somebody stated here that all chars under 128 remain unchanged. However, 'Delphi in a Unicode world' states otherwise. So, there is a way to use something like #9 in Delphi XE or porting the code from Delphi 7 to Delphi Unicode involves massive code changes?

Comment: I guess you are asking about the problem that does not exist. I can't imagine the problem with #0..#127 characters while converting to Unicode. If you have a problem, show the code.

Comment: @Serg - So, I can just leave all numeric characters as they are (well, except the FillChar of course). This is great. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The low half of ANSI codes [#0..#127] does not change after conversion to Unicode, so you should not bother about it. The high half [#128..#255] is more complicated. The compiler interprets lines

```
const s1:AnsiString = #200;
const s2:UnicodeString = #200;
```

depending on {$HIGHCHARUNICODE} directive

```
{$HIGHCHARUNICODE OFF}          // default setting on Delphi 2009
const s1:AnsiString = #200;     // Ord(s1[1]) = $C8 = 200
const s2:UnicodeString = #200;  // Ord(s2[1]) depends on Codepage
                                //  on my Win1251 = $418  

{$HIGHCHARUNICODE ON}
const s1:AnsiString = #200;     // Ord(s1[1]) depends on Codepage
                                //   on my Win1251 = $45
const s2:UnicodeString = #200;  // Ord(s2[1]) = $C8 = 200
```

#200 is 'И' on Win1251 codepage. The Unicode codepoint for 'И' is $418.

On the other hand, in Unicode #200 is 'È'. Win1251 does not have 'È' character and Unicode -> Win1251 conversion transforms it to 'E' which is #$45 for all ANSI codepages.

With {$HIGHCHARUNICODE OFF} the compiler interprets #128..#255 characters as ANSI characters depending on system codepage and, if necessary, converts them to unicode codepoints.

With {$HIGHCHARUNICODE ON} the compiler interprets #128..#255 characters as Unicode codepoints and, if necessary, converts them to ANSI characters with possible loss.

---

**Update**

I see now the problem code from the [Nick's article](http://dn.embarcadero.com/article/38693) that works wrong on Unicode Delphi:

```
var
  Buf: array[0..32] of Char;
begin
  FillChar(Buf, Length(Buf), #9);
  ShowMessage(Format('%d %d %d', [Ord(Buf[0]), Ord(Buf[0]), Ord(Buf[16])]));
end;
```

but that is an example of wrong `FillChar` procedure usage; `FillChar` just fills the destination buffer with bytes (BTW only the first half of Buf in the above example) and ignores all the new Unicode stuff. `FillChar` should be renamed by FillBytes now, and forbidden to use a character (#9) for the third argument.

Comment: +1 for `{$HIGHCHARUNICODE}`. The default OFF makes a lot of sense because it allows code to compile unchanged.

Comment: Deleted my answer because I like yours better!

Comment: @Cosmin: My post does not answer the OP question what happens with low #0..#127 characters in Unicode (nothing happens). It answers a different question (what happens with high #128..#255 characters) which is not so evident and often misunderstood.

Comment: @Serg, add a line to your answer about the < 128 chars, because it's related to the behavior controlled by `{$HIGHCHARUNICODE}`. In fact that information should be on Embarcadero's [documentation wiki on HIGHCHARUNICODE](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE/en/HIGHCHARUNICODE_directive_(Delphi)) as well.

Comment: @Cosmin: Done, though my answer mostly is not about the OP question. :)

Comment: +1 also from me. If I understand correctly, because the default behavior for HIGHCHARUNICODE is OFF, Delphi XE treats chars 0 to 255 exactly as Delphi 7?? Or it does that ONLY if they are assigned to a ANSI variable?

Comment: Then what happens in this case: var W: WideChar; W := #$80 ??? Delphi manual says I will obtain $20AC instead of $80.